# C Passing and Reassinging Pointers in Functions

Tags: c, pointers

Here's the function in question. Why does x not change, despite having ptr reference it's memory address? Similarly why doesn't y change?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int func (int a, int *b)
{
  int *ptr = &a;
  *ptr += 5;
  ptr = b;
  *ptr -= 3;
  return a;
}

int main ()
{
  int x = 2;
  int y = 8;
  int ret = func (x, &y);
  printf ("x: %d\n", x);
  printf ("y: %d\n", y);
  printf ("ret: %d\n", ret);
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: yes y does change. Sorry.

Comment: "Why does x not change, despite having ptr reference". Where is there a pointer reference to `x`? `ptr = &a` is a pointer to a **local** variable `a` and not to `x`. In C, all function parameters are passed by value so `a` is a different variable to `x` but with the same value.

Comment: regarding: `int *ptr = &a;`  gets the address of some place on the call parameter list rather than the address of the variable back in `main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int func (int a, int *b)
```

'a' is passed by value. Inside func() a has its own memory allocated, so anything you do to it does not affect the variable that was passed in. 'b' is a pointer to an int so changing the data at that address is still visible outside the scope of func(). Hence, x doesn't change, but y does.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!